# 'Graph' object has no attribute 'node'

Tags: python, pandas, graph, networkx

I have this code which runs perfectly fine.

```
G = nx.Graph()

num_row = len(attr_df)
keys = attr_df.columns
attrs = {}

for i in range(num_row):
    G.add_node(attr_df['MATNR'][i], PSTAT= attr_df['PSTAT'][i])
```

and if I was to call

```
G.nodes()
```

I would get a long list of all the nodes.

But when I call

```
G.node[0]
```

to look at an individual node and its properties, I get:

```
AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'node'
```

Comment: Please see the documentation on the correct syntax: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.nodes.html .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

G.nodes() is a method that returns a NodeView object. There is no value being created called G.node that can be iterated over.

You can cast NodeView to a list like this `list(NodeViewObj)`, and therefore access the first element like so:

```py
list(G.nodes())[0]
```

[The documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.nodes.html) details this

Answer (score 0):

While @Libra's answer is correct, it's also possible to access a specific node via `G.nodes[node_name]` syntax. For example, the following should work if node `0` is a node in `G`:

```py
G.nodes[0]
```

This provides a convenient way to access nodes, especially if they have a non-numeric name, when relying on their position in `list(G.nodes())` is not so reliable, while you can still call out them using their string name, e.g. `G.nodes['B']`

Comment: The asker left this comment on an answer I have since deleted when I suggested they try the same thing:
"Gives me: KeyError: 0"